# Error BadRequestException: You must use the customer-specific endpoint

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-media-convert

I am trying to create job of mediaconverter aws service through lambda but I m getting error

> "Error BadRequestException: You must use the customer-specific
> endpoint"

```
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
    var mediaconvert = new AWS.MediaConvert("https://xyzyzyzzz.mediaconvert.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
    console.log("End Point Set");
    await mediaconvert.createJob(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log('started execution');
    if (err){ console.log(err, err.stack); 
        console.log("non promise error");     
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200, 
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    } // an error occurred
    else   {  console.log("non promise no error");       
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200, 
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    }
        // successful response
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to find you mediaconvert endpoint is to go to `mediaconvert service -> from left panel select account` and there's your endpoint.

I found mine `https://xxxxx.mediaconvert.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is the error you get when the endpoint is not specified or if it's an invalid value. The constructor for MediaConvert accepts an object, not just a string, as outlined in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/MediaConvert.html#constructor-property). You need to pass the endpoint URI in an object like so:

```
var mediaconvert = new AWS.MediaConvert({
  endpoint: "https://xyzyzyzzz.mediaconvert.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
});
```

For context, the endpoint can be found in the console in the MediaConvert service under the Account section or it can be fetched through the API as [outlined here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/emc-examples-getendpoint.html). In general, this value should be cached as it has a much lower request rate limit than the other MediaConvert endpoints. There is one endpoint per account per region.

Answer (score -2):

You did not specify the params in your createJob call.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/MediaConvert.html#createJob-property) tells you what you need in order to create a job.

Comment: I specify param in my code, dont have any issue with param

Comment: The error mentioned is a result of a missing endpoint, not missing params. I assume he assigned to `params` earlier in the code.